# SOBO - where are the settings in admin?

Tags: docusignapi

From the documentation, where exactly is the settings for these 2 in the admin site?

Users who want to authenticate on behalf of other account users must have the following settings enabled to use SOBO:

```
apiAccountWideAccess
allowSendOnBehalfOf
```

If you are setting user permissions through the DocuSign web console these correspond to the Account-Wide Rights and Send On Behalf Of Rights (API) settings.

Comment: I had to switch to "Classic" version of Admin to find it.  Hit the dropdown under your picture and choose Preferences. From there, it is under the permissions tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch to "Classic" version of Admin to find it. Hit the dropdown under your picture and choose Preferences. From there, it is under the permissions tab.